# twitter bootstrap 2 column fixed layout broken

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap

my website 
http://whoisdomains.co.uk/

is using twitter bootstrap
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html

I am attemptimg to use the two column layout
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

The code they give is

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">...</div>
  <div class="span8">...</div>
</div>
```

I however swop the 8 and the 4 around, but dont see why this should make a difference. AS you can see frommy website i have put some dummy text in but its broken and overlaps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 very long words in spans so they can't be wrapped. Put some space characters into the words and it will be aligned, something like that:

```
<div class="span8">dskjdskjdskjlsdjlsdj ldjslkd sjkldsjklsdjlsdkjskldj ldksjldskjklsdjl dkjdlsjsdkjkladmdklmc kldmslkcmdlasmkmlkdjslkaj dlkjdsakjsdljlk sjljds</div>
<div class="span4">dkjsasdjsdhakhfl kjhdlkah fklhskldfha skjdhfk hsdklhfkjsdh ajklhfjklshadl kfhsjkadhfkjlh dsfjlhjaksdhfjk hjhdsajlkhdfljhasd ljhflkdhlkfhlkhdskfd</div>
```

If you check the page using console like firebug you'll see that width of the span divs is correct.

Comment: You can actually correct this with the `word-wrap: break-word` if it is a problem that you can't have this behavior

Comment: Lesson here: use some real world placeholder text (Lorem Ipsum will do just fine).